# Setting Variables in x86

Tags: visual-studio, variables, assembly, x86

I am using Microsoft visual studio, and have been avoiding variables for a long time. I have read many pages from my book and looked it up online, and they all say the same thing about setting your variables. However, whenever I do exactly the same thing as I am instructed I am bombarded with error messages for unapparent reasons. Here's an example.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    __asm
    {
.DATA
string BYTE "CELLAR", 0
    }

    return 0;
}

// end of program code
```

I get three errors here. a C2400 saying .DATA isn't a thing, another C2400 saying string Byte "Cellar" , 0 isn't right, and a C4405 saying BYTE is a reserved word. I've tried replacing BYTE with WORD, db or dw, but that doesn't help either. I'm doing exactly what my book says yet I'm still getting errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please format your code as code. It just takes a click on the `{}` button!

Comment: Guess your book is about MASM, and not about inline assembly. One of the limitations of `__asm` is that [you cannot declare any data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70hd396.aspx).

Comment: Okay that makes sense. We haven't learnd anything regarding the absence of _asm though, but would I just continue to code like I normally would in assembly? Should I put the .DATA section before the _asm?

Comment: @BoPersson: you should perhaps clarify that this is the case for MSVC++. It is not necessarily so in the inline assemblers for other development tools and other languages.

Comment: @Superskee: You do not declare a `.DATA` section. The data section is declared by the compiler, if you simply declare global variables (that are variables declared outside any function) in C++. Local variables are handled in the function prologue, also by the compiler.

Comment: `Should I put the .DATA section before the _asm?` No, you should put it in a separate file with a `.asm` extension if you want to really use MASM, rather than just MSVC inline asm.  (Or any other assembler, like NASM or YASM).  Everything outside an `_asm` block in a .c file has to be valid C syntax, of course.